# Jquery UI calendar issue with Grails 2.5.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grails

I'm using `Grails 2.5.1` and `JqueryUI calendar` , in the view pages the months and years don't show correctly as the attached shots, I tried on different `Internet Explorer` and `Chrome` and getting the same

Months:

[image: The months]

Years:

[image: The years failed]

Any explanation about this error and how to fix it?

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu8fp.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqg9s.png

Comment: any ideas to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found what is wrong, the theme what was used in the Jquery UI got a white background and the writing font is white too, so this makes them doesn't show, just changed the theme and all went fine.